# Format time only with Luxon

Tags: javascript, luxon

I have a time saved as a string in my database.  I'm trying to parse that time using Luxon, and then set various date parts to my various controls.  While I'm not getting any errors during the parsing, I'm getting unexpected values.

The time I'm testing with: 12:05 AM America/Chicago

I'm attempting to parse as follows.

```
const date = DateTime.fromFormat(value, 'hh:mm a z');
```

The output is

Hour: 1 (incorrect)

Minute: 05 (correct)

Meridien: (AM) (correct)

Timezone: America/New_York (incorrect)

Comment: What timezone is your computer set to?

Comment: Got a feeling that it's parsing the date correctly and it's just being shown in your local timezone as "12:05 AM America/Chicago" and "1:05 AM America/New_York" both represent the same moment in time.

Comment: Local timezone is America/New_York, however I just want to view the time as it was provided.  Is there another way to get it from its original format?  Not sure if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If you set `opts.setZone` to true, it will keep the DateTime in Chicago time, so any output will be displayed in that timezone.

To display the time in your local zone you can use [`DateTime.toLocal()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetolocal).

You can switch zone again by using the [DateTime.setZone()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone) function if you need to.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const value = '12:05 AM America/Chicago';

const date = DateTime.fromFormat(value, 'hh:mm a z', { setZone: true });

console.log('Timezone:', date.toFormat('z'))
console.log('Time (Chicago):', date.toFormat('hh:mm a'))
console.log('Time (local):', date.toLocal().toFormat('hh:mm a'))
console.log('Time (New York):', date.setZone('America/New_York').toFormat('hh:mm a'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```